# Hazelcast query array objects in .net

Tags: hazelcast

I have a complex structure to work around. Basically I have a root model class which contains lots of sub classes as an array. Now I wanted apply SQL predicate on top of these values for which I prepared a map cache.

For now am trying to retrieve it as like `array(any).attribute`, but it doesn't work out for me. Hazelcast3.6.3.dll is been used.

Comment: I am getting results while applying queries as like Car[0].wheel. but, whereas it is not working in the case of Car[any].wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 3.6 Hazelcast supports querying in an array or collection of objects and since 3.6.3 it also supports such queries in the Portable data format.

Query like `array(any).attribute == sth` should work for you.
Could you post a code snippet with what you're running to make sure it's 100% correct?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got it working right now. Its because of data problem was not working previously.

Comment: Sure, feel free to accept my answer if you're satisfied.

Answer (score -1):

A working sample can be found below. 
https://github.com/cwijayasundara/Hazelcast-Continuous-Query). Pls have a look at the 4 classes in the rnd package.